# Regex expression in Javascript to strip script tags and further more

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, replace

I would like to use regex to strip a html text. I want to get rid of all script, style and < ! -- tags.

Could u please help me figure out how to do that.

What i got so far is the following function, which sadly isn't working.

```
console.log(doTheMagic('This is a test < !-- hello --> Bla bla'));

function doTheMagic(text){
text = text.replace(/(<!--.\/-->)/g, '');       
return text;
}
```

I found out the preg_replace function expression in php would be like this, but I can't get it working within javascript:

```
'@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   /* strip out javascript */
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            /* strip out HTML tags */
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    /* strip style tags properly */
        '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         /* strip multi-line comments */
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

`/(<!--.\/-->)/g` would match `<!--x/-->`, try using `.*` instead of `.`, because the dot alone, will only match one character.

But i would recommend to read the comment you got, too